# Generating Unique URLs

Tags: mongodb

So, i'm running into an issue. I've got a server that is trying to generate "pretty" URLs, based off of the data they are being provided. For the sake of the discussion, lets say titles of blog posts. The url for this obviously needs to be unique, as to properly represent the resource. Well, correct me if i am wrong.. but this is not a simple problem in MongoDB?

At first i googled some type of auto-incrementing field. This returned what i expected, but there was a glaring issue.. 10gen advises against it.

> Warning Generally in MongoDB, you would not use an auto-increment pattern for the _id field, **or any field**, because it does not scale for databases with larger numbers of documents. Typically the default value ObjectId is more ideal for the _id.

Note the bolded text. 10gen doesn't advise you incrementing any field.

So, back to the problem. If i hand the server a post title, and i want it to create a post, i expect it to automatically change my title to a unique title. For example, if i create three posts with the title `foo`, i want the server to create urls for `/foo`, `/foo1`, `/foo2`. Though, it could be any form of unique addition, the point here is that the server is handling the dirty work of creating unique urls, rather than simply failing and making the user repeatedly try to come up with a unique url.

With that said, how is this done in the "MongoDB way"? 10gen advises *against* incrementing, and basically the only unique string i can seem to find is the `ObjectID`, but `/foo50bbe1573b60ff0000000002` is hardly "pretty". You have to admit, if you're forced to use `/foo50bbe1573b60ff0000000002`, you may as well just use `/50bbe1573b60ff0000000002`. "pretty" was long gone after the first 5 characters.

So, any thoughts/opinions on how to handle this problem in a MongoDB friendly manner?

**Potential Answer:**
One horrible solution is to repeat the document creation until unique passes, but a maximum of X times. For example,

1. you could try writing it with the title
2. if that fails write it with the title plus the increment value of objectid *(say, 00002)*
3. If that fails, write it with the whole god damn objectid. We've already lost at this point anyway.

**Potential Answer:**
Another potential answer, is simply doing what 10gen advises against, making an incrementing field.

Out of the two above solutions, i'm sure each is more efficient at varying methods.. eg: solution 1 is probably best if your unique field is very likely to be unique, say 40 characters of user inputed data. It is potentially slow as molasses if you're dealing with 4 characters.

**Edit: Better Answer**
A combination of the two would be best, i think. Have a collection of "original" urls *(eg: `/foo`)*, with a count of how many times they have been written to. Append the count to your target url, and you have a unique url. I believe that this would be a balance between the performance problems that 10gen advises against, while also still giving you the incrementing.

Comment: I don't understand why you introduced the most friendly solution foo, foo1, foo2 then went on to talk about some unfriendly hex string. The answer is: create a table of friendly slugs which you can quickly check for uniqueness when generating a slug and join it to your posts when looking for a post using the slug which is in the URL.

Comment: Because foo1/2/3 etc, are all forms of incrementing. 10gen advises *against* that

Comment: "Generally in MongoDB, you would not use an auto-increment pattern" **!=** "don't use the most sensible solution"

Comment: Well a sensible solution isn't one that incurs significant performance problems, which is what 10gen seems to be warning against. Though, i edited my post with what i believe would be the most sensible solution.

Comment: So instead of just storing a unique string per post, your solution is to store a possible duplicated string per post, and when a user visits a URL for which the non-unique string may only be a partial match, figure out that there isn't a match, trim off the integer, then see if there's a match and if so find the nth entry. Nice performance enhancement there.

Comment: Option 1 may not really be that horrible, post titles are rarely the same.  Another choice is to use a time stamp as part of the name.  Time has his nasty habit of incrementing whether we like it or not.

Comment: Unless ALL your post titles are foo, the amount of what you consider to be an incremental pattern is going to be somewhat negligible. You're potentially making it difficult for yourself **and reducing performance** because of one line about something mildly related to the data you're storing.

Comment: I'd like to chime in and say that there is a difference between an auto_increment field in a database table and a URL-generation scheme that uses a "form of incrementing". The reason MongoDB advises against *auto-increment fields* is that there is a performance hit when inserting a new row to determine what the current max value is in order to generate the new auto-increment value. There is no such performance problem with inventing your own server-side URL-generation scheme which differentiates between posts via timestamp or what-have-you.

Comment: @popnoodles I think you severely misunderstood my edit, if you think "**and when a user visits a URL for which the non-unique string may only be a partial match, figure out that there isn't a match, trim off the integer, then see if there's a match and if so find the nth entry.**" is what i meant. The method i described is an incrementing field, nothing more. Also may i say that you come off as a bit of a prick, it may be unintended, but i just wanted to warn you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

10gen is warning against putting some kind of pessimistic concurrency in place or using server side javascript to find the current max key for the ENTIRE collection and then incrementing it  and returning the new _id. MongoDB is designed for huge collections that often depend on fire and forget inserts/updates. By the nature of the application you're describing, none of these are an obstacle (much more important than 10gen's advice is your knowledge of the problem domain and how this might interact with the item they have given you a warning about).

A better scheme that doesn't go against 10gen's advice would be to construct a url out of some other attribute of the post, i.e. the username, the date and time it was created, etc.

In your example of a blog post, you might have url paths that look like

> /posts/userName/2013/3/5/title-of-my-post

You'll have to decide the actual scheme based on the attributes of the resource you're displaying, but that is a good start. In this example, unless a single user creates two posts on the same day with the exact same title, there will be no problem ensuring unique urls. Your document in this case may look like:

> {
>       _id: ObjectId(...),
>       userName: "userName",
>       dateCreated: ISODate("2013-03-05"),
>       title: "title of my post",
>       body: "..." 
>   }

With a unique index on `{dateCreated: -1, userName: 1, title: 1}` (this would set you up nicely on sorting and ordered posts by user, also).

Comment: wait for it "but years and months are incremental." +1 Sensible answer.

Comment: It looks a bit like what WordPress does, and they just append a sequence when they get a duplicate.

Comment: The funny thing about the way they've worded that advice is that when you dig further into index optimization, you find that ensuring items are inserted into the index incrementally is important. I'm almost positive they've put it there to warn the really old-school SQL devs who still select from the table to find the previous max key before inserting a new record.